# Arduino not connecting to Wifi

Tags: arduino, wifi

I'm trying to connect my Arduino Opta Wifi to my Wifi network with the following code:

```
//WiFi
const char SSID[] = "<insert ssid here>";
const char PASSWORD[] = "<insert password here>";
WiFiClient wifiClient;

int wifiWaiting = 0;

void setup() {
  pinMode(LED_D0, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_D1, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_D2, OUTPUT);
  pinMode(LED_D3, OUTPUT);
  digitalWrite(LED_D0, HIGH);
  connectWifi();
}

void loop() {
  delay(100);
}

void connectWifi() {

  if (WiFi.status() == WL_CONNECTED) {
    digitalWrite(LED_D1, OUTPUT);
    return;
  }

  WiFi.begin(SSID, PASSWORD);
  int attempts = 0;
  while (WiFi.status() != WL_CONNECTED) {
      wifiWaiting = 1 - wifiWaiting;
      digitalWrite(LED_D3, wifiWaiting);
      delay(500);
  }
  digitalWrite(LED_D1, HIGH);
  digitalWrite(LED_D3, LOW);
}
```

However, the Opta is not connecting. The problem is not with SSID and password, as the same ones work on my laptop. Also, there should not be any restrictions for new devices to connect to the network.

When I try running the program, the LED_03 keeps blinking indefinitely (=Wifi not connected)

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the SSID you’re connecting to is 2.4ghz not 5ghz.  I setup a separate “Arduino” SSID on my network.